# Use returned values from a query in the same procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm quite new to pgpsql. I have two tables - product and product_category - with a one to many relationship. I'm creating a procedure to insert a value into the category table if it doesn't exist and I would like to use the id for the category to insert a product.

I've tried using an alias for the first insert and then returning the id value so I can select it, but I get an error.

What's the right way for using returned in the same procedure values in pgpsql?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_product(name VARCHAR, category VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
  WITH ins_category AS(
    INSERT INTO product_category(name) 
    VALUES('laptops')
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id
    )
  INSERT INTO product(name, category)
  VALUES(name, ins_category.id); // HERE IS THE ERROR
  COMMIT;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`.

```
WITH ins_category
AS
(
...
)
INSERT INTO product (name,
                     category)
                    SELECT name,
                           ins_category.id
                           FROM ins_category;
```

Comment: Which is a better way using a select or declaring a variable and a return into with the category id?

Comment: @S.Schenk: Better in terms of what?